# How to compress a HTML form image, replace it and send it through the same form submission ( jQuery, Symfony )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony4

I have a form with input images and I would like to rotate and reduce them before submiting the form. At this point I know how to rotate and reduce them, but I can not manage to inject them in the form so they are sended though the same POST request as if they didn't change.

I have a Symfony 4 app which has a form to upload products. This form contains a cuple of images with a preview box. The form POST is done by the default HTML form submission call, so Symfony does almost all the job.

ProductController.php:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {

    $product = new Product();

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $viewVars = [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && !empty($form->get('image')->getData())) {

        /** @var UploadedFile $image */
        $image = $form->get('image')->getData();
        if(!empty($image)) {
            $pImage = new ProductImage();
            $pImage->setImage($this->amazonS3Service->uploadUploadedFile($image));
            $pImage->setProduct($product);
            $product->setImage($pImage);
            $product->addImage($pImage);
        }

        $entityManager->persist($product);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('product', ['id' => $product->getId()]);

    }

    return $this->render('upload/upload.html.twig', $viewVars);
}
```

upload.html:

```
<form action="/upload" class="product-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="product_image" name="product[image]" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

upload.js:

```
readAndCompressImage(file, config_compression)
    .then(resizedImage => {
                    $('#product_image').remove();
                    $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'hidden',
                        id: 'product_image',
                        name: 'product[image]',
                        value: resizedImage //This is a blob
                    }).appendTo('form');
```

I would like to upload the resized and rotated images in a way that symfony does all the request stuff for me. 
At this point I can only upload the images which I selected on the input, not the modified ones. The hidden input which I added is not properly managed by symfony on the server side ( the $image variable is null )

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to compress the image into a Blob and append it to a FormData object for submission. The same should work for your image rotation:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        let originalFileName = input.files[0].name;
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            let img = new Image();
            img.src = e.target.result;

            img.onload = function() {
                let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                // You can adjust these values for better compression or quality
                const MAX_WIDTH = 600;
                const MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
                let width = img.width;
                let height = img.height;

                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }

                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    // Create a new File object and replace the original one in the input element
                    const newFile = new File([blob], originalFileName, { type: "image/jpeg", lastModified: new Date() });
                    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
                    dataTransfer.items.add(newFile);
                    document.getElementById("image_upload").files = dataTransfer.files;
                }, "image/jpeg", 0.8);

            };
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

// Add an event listener to the file input
document.getElementById("image_upload").addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value) {  // Check if a file has been selected
        readURL(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

At the end, I managed to do it by inserting HiddenType components on the form and then introducing inside them the base64 result image though javascript.

Comment: This is a bad solution as base64 would increase the file size approximately 33%